# How do regular expressions work behind the scenes (at the CPU level)?

Tags: regex, string, optimization, filter

Do interpreters and compilers compare (and ultimately match) two strings for a potential match in a character-by-character and left-to-right fashion?  Or is there an underlying binary value (e.g., a bit pattern) assigned to each string in a comparison function?  Or does it depend on the string being encoded in a certain way (ASCII or UTF-32), or the interpreter, compiler, database engine, or programming language?

Redesigning the data store (data files or databases) is a considerable effort.  The answer to a similar question on stackoverflow didn't definitively describe the encoding question (whether bit patterns were being evaluated or actual alphabetic characters).  The answer to this question could be important for an optimization effort.

I don't want to know how to implement a regular expression (e.g., write my own).  I want to know for educational purposes for the benefit of using existing regular expressions in an optimal way (e.g., when it is time to design data to be stored as a composition of substrings, should I be mindful of the left to right evaluation).  A similar StackOverflow question's [answer](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) (which is a link that has an untrusted certificate to view it) focuses on finite automata (the theory of how strings are compared).  That answer emphasizes how it can work and the computational complexity of comparing strings.  It does imply that there is a left-to-right character evaluation.  I don't think it was definitive by any means.  The article was largely specific to Perl and the language agnostic Thomson non-deterministic finite automata algorithm.  I would like to know for sure with these three technology combinations: 1) Java native functions using ASCII data files, 2) MySQL (table data and SELECT statements), and 3) with Python native functions and UTF-32 data files.

My question and approach is different from the older post in that I am not trying to develop a parser for doing regexes. I'm trying to architect data for future development.  I want to know how to utilize existing regex tools in an optimal way.  I believe stackoverflow is the right forum because it is central to regexes, and this question in its original and less verbose form has been voted up.

I want to know at the CPU level, are bit patterns the representations of the characters in the string?  Is there a short-lived index of the bit patterns corresponding to each character of the strings participating in the  comparisons wherein one string is anchored?  I would think the technology (e.g., the database, the programming language, and/or the encoding of the data) would vary.

Comment: You would have to look at the source of the language implementing the regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a parser for regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639574/writing-a-parser-for-regular-expressions)

Comment: There are some not very obvious speed-ups. For some REs it could help to adapt the technique used to search for a string in text, where one generates a ‘skip-length table’ in which you look up what would be the last matching character if the string were at a given position and are told how far you can advance the trial position.

Comment: REs are also not programmes but definitions, and various applications might benefit from different optimisations: ee.g. do you want to iterate through all matches in a chunk of text (e.g. a line) or just find the first match? Do you want to replace the matching text?

Answer (score 7):

There are two big families of regex engines, called **NFA** and **DFA** (I'm using the terminology from Jeffrey Friedl's book):

- *Nondeterministic* finite automaton
- *Deterministic* finite automaton

A NFA implementation will *roughly* work the following way:

- Keep a pointer to a *current offset* in the *input string*
- Keep a pointer to the *current position* in the *pattern* (which is interpreted as a graph or tree).

Then use the pattern as a *recipe* of how to advance in the input string. If the pattern says `a` for instance, and if the *current input offset* points to an `a` character, then that character will be *consumed* and both pointers will advance to the next position. If the character doesn't match, there will be a backtrack (the input pointer will go to a previous valid position and the pattern pointer will be set to a different possible alternative at the input position).

The point is that **the recognition is driven by the pattern**.

(the above explanation is *very* rough, as it doesn't include optimizations etc - and modern patterns cannot be implemented with a formal automaton anyway)

A DFA implementation works the other way around:

There is still *one* input pointer, but there are *multiple* pattern pointers. The input pattern will advance character by character, and the pattern pointers will keep track of a valid state in the pattern for the given input.

The **recognition is driven by the input**.

Both these methods have very different properties:

- *NFA* engines can offer much more features, but their running time is dependent on the combination of the input and the pattern itself
- *DFA* engines offer less features, but their complexity is *O(n)*, where *n* is the length of the input string.

Some regex engines (such as PCRE) can implement both recognition methods. I recommend you read the [PCRE docs](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2matching.html) about the two matching algorithms, which explain the differences in more technical terms.

As to the *actual* implementation, it highly depends on the regex engine itself.  PCRE has several of them:

- A NFA algorithm based on a tree traversal approach
- An optimized version of the above based on JIT compilation (one version for each supported instruction set)
- A DFA implementation

So you can actually see there are several possible approaches for NFA alone. Other engines have different implementations that allow for a different feature set. For instance, .NET's regexes can be matched left-to-right, or right-to-left and thus can easily provide variable-length lookbehind, whereas PCRE's lookbehind is implemented by temporarily shifting the input pointer to the left by the lookbehind's expected input length, and performing a left-to-right match from this offset.

Comment: For all known languages, is the optimal data store is designed (when the composition is arbitrary) strings that have singular (most likely to be unique) substrings toward the left?  There would be a potential benefit if strings were aggregates of smaller substrings if the uniqueness happened at the left, right?  The right most portion of the composite string could appear to the right. If I am storing composites of human names, 5 sizes, and 4 colors, the names would be relatively unique. So for optimal regexes, I should store the name, color, then the size right?  johnLargeRed, susanMediumBlue

Comment: @Yousef I'm not entirely sure I understand your question accurately, but yes, there is a benefit in putting the most discriminating input to the left, especially for NFA engines, as this reduces backtracking. DFAs would be less impacted but there still could be a benefit in failing fast for non-matching inputs.

Comment: Is there a technology combination that wouldn't/couldn't do backtracking by using binary values for string comparisons?  Sometimes there is a hash value assigned to a file or value (e.g., when you do a chksum).  This hash value is unique.  Is this question appropriate here at stackoverflow?  Should I make a separate question for this?

Comment: @Yousef DFAs don't backtrack, ever. But your question makes me believe you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I'd advise you to think about *what* you're trying to achieve and post a separate question with the *actual problem* you're trying to solve. Keep in mind the solution doesn't have to involve regexes at all, so stick to the problem, and don't limit yourself to your *attempted approach*.

Comment: I don't know why Jeffrey Friedl choose these names, but everyone able to read other sources as his book have to be at least irritated. I think it's a mistake to keep repeating it (apart from that I like the book). NFA an DFA can both offer the exact same features. They can "only" match the same languages. .net and other implementation use a virtual machine approach to extend functionality. There are other techniques I'm not aware of for sure - but at the end: if you add a stack to a FSM, it's no longer an FSM..

Comment: @Wolfgang agreed, as I said in the answer, today's patterns aren't regular anymore and can't just be implemented using a FSA. That's why I'm not really at ease using these terms, but the historical approach has many educational benefits. However, DFAs can't really support backreferences for instance (I'm not aware of any DFA-based regex engine that supports them), but this construct isn't regular in the first place. I think the terminology can still stand, as a DFA closely matches the input-driven approach, in that there's a single possible state change for a given input character.

Comment: That's the problem. NFAs can't support backreferences, too. NFAs and DFAs are equal in terms of power (you can convert any NFA into a DFA and back). The only difference is, that a DFA is always in a single state (deterministic) while NFAs can be in multiple states at the same time (that's the non-deterministic part)... There's nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions don't specify implementation details. It's up to the language to decide the best way to compile them to machine code. For example, this [regex.c](http://hte.sourceforge.net/doxygenized-0.8.0pre1/regex_8c-source.html) implementation looks like it goes more than one character at a time.

Comment: I'm gonna need to take a shower after looking through that source code...

Answer (score 0):

The way regular expressions work is an implementation detail. They can be implemented one way, or second way.

In fact, some of the languages implement them inefficiently.

If you want to understand more, I can refer you to this article: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: "One way or second way"?  Can you please elaborate?