# Which regular expression engine type does R use as a standard?

Tags: regex, r

Jeffrey Friedl lists 3 main types of regex engines in his book "Mastering Regular Expressions":

- Traditional NFA
- POSIX NFA
- DFA (POSIX or not)

Which of these does R use as a standard?

Comment: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/ says TRE uses NFA,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding (But I have not found this in official documents) is that the R regex functions by default use the tcl regex library which is a hybrid of DFA and NFA.

The engine will first scan the regexp for any non-DFA compatible pieces and extract parts that are DFA (so strips out back references and other things that are only available in NFA).  It then tries to find a match to this (possibly) simplified pattern using a DFA engine.  If it cannot find a match then the full regex will not match and it returns with a failure.  If it finds a match then it goes back and matches the full regex using an NFA engine (I think traditional/non-posix), but starting at the location where the simplified match occurred.  This is much faster (for both non-matches and matches) than a straight NFA engine, but still lets you use all the things in an NFA that a DFA does not support.

If you specify `perl=TRUE` in any function then it switches to the pcre library which is most like a traditional NFA (though I understand that it is not F, A, or traditional).

Comment: `?regex` cites  the TRE library documentation.

Answer (score 10):

The `?regex` page cites the TRE documentation. Near the top of the [`grep.c` source](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/grep.c) we see:

```
/* As from TRE 0.8.0, tre.h replaces regex.h */
#include <tre/tre.h>
```

And copying my earlier comment: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp says TRE uses NFA. Then PCRE is used for `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: And `stringr` uses [ICU regex flavor](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew (My hazy memories, so corrections solicited.) In the beginning `stringr` was written in base R as a student project under hadley's tutelage, but its performance suffered in comparison with `stringi` so the authors remade `stringr` as a wrapper for `stringi`.

Comment: I'm not sure where that memory of `stringr` being a student project came from, but reviewing the DESCRIPTION files of the package's Archive, it seems that the switch to `stringi` code was around 2015 with the release of ver 1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at `?regex` for all the gory details ([HTML version](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)).  There are several options.

To quote one portion:

> This section covers the regular expressions allowed in the default mode
>       of grep, regexpr, gregexpr, sub, gsub and strsplit. They use an
>       implementation of the POSIX 1003.2 standard: that allows some scope
>       for interpretation and the interpretations here are those currently
>       used by R. The implementation supports some extensions to the standard.

Also check further down in the help page about "Perl-like expressions", which use the PCRE engine.

Comment: This still does not answer the question. I understand it's POSIX, but is it NFA or DFA?

Comment: @histelheim as backreferences are supported in POSIX mode, that'll be a NFA engine.

Comment: I don't know, and those terms do not appear in the R documentation or packages.  `library("sos"); findFn("DFA"); findFn("NFA")` return only trivial, unrelated answers.  Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: @Bryan that's regex terminology that has nothing to do with R. NFA = *Nondeterministic Finite Automaton*, DFA = *Deterministic Finite Automaton*. Much too broad to explain it here.

Comment: @joran yes, I've explained it myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30416338/3764814), but there's way more to that to cover it all in depth.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to learn that there is yet another layer of complexity to the whole regex game...