# Regex search & replace versatile lookbehind

Tags: r, regex, sublimetext3

I have an R function which is similar to this:

```
logFun <- function(msg1, msg2){
  return(sprintf("%s: %s", msg1, msg2))
}
logFun("123", "456")
```

It's used in a lot of places, and not always entered nicely e.g. these are all example use cases:

```
var1 <- "aa"
var2 <- "bb"
logFun(var1, var2)
logFun("aa", var2)
logFun("aa", "bb")
logFun(var1, "bb")
logFun(msg1 = "aa", msg2 = "bb")
logFun(msg1 = var1, msg2 = "bb")
...
```

Say I had a new function e.g.

```
logFun2 <- function(msg1, msg2, type){
  return(sprintf("[%s] %s: %s", type, msg1, msg2))
}
logFun2("123", "456", "bug")
```

and the function calls have to be preserved `(msg1, msg2, type)`, as many have been converted from `logFun` to `logFun2`. What I am trying to do with Sublime is to replace the list of use cases above with the following:

```
logFun2(var1, var2, type = "bug")
logFun2("aa", var2, type = "bug")
logFun2("aa", "bb", type = "bug")
logFun2(var1, "bb", type = "bug")
logFun2(msg1 = "aa", msg2 = "bb", type = "bug")
logFun2(msg1 = var1, msg2 = "bb", type = "bug")
```

I've read some bits around lookbehind matching, but finding it tricky to find out if its a doable job, or whether I should find another solution to the problem. With https://regex101.com/, I've managed to isolate the `logFun(` part with `(?<=logFun\()`, but not sure where to go from here. Any guidance would be appreciated :)

Thanks, Jonny

**Edit 1**

**Q:** Why cannot you define your `logFun2` function with default value for argument `type = "bug"` and just replace `logFun` with `logFun2`?

**A:** In reality, we don't just have `logFun`. We say have functions `logBug`, `logInfo`, `logWarning` etc. We are then changing these in to a singular function `logGeneral` e.g. `logBug` becomes `logGeneral(.., .., type = "bug")`.
So, yep you are right we could for one type of log specify the default and not worry about that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple types, then one could use a regex for all of them:

```
\blog(\w+)\(([^()]+)\)
```

And then replace by using the PCRE lowercase transformation \L for the type name after "log".

Replace string:

```
logFun2(\2, type = "\L\1")
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/fjo9ZZ/1)

[Also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035535/)

Comment: Hey again, this has worked great, but I've found some annoying cases in the code :s. Any ideas how to get round something like

`logDebug(paste("annoying", "case"), 
                      msg2 = "data_prep")`

over multiple lines, here, it stops at the first bracket, due to the clause (perfectly reasonable :))
Thanks

Comment: One way is to change the "more then 1 of anything but ( or )" `[^()]+`. For example: `\blog(Debug|Bug|Info|Warning|Fun)\(([^\r\n]+)\)`.  Which assumes the string is on 1 line. Because the default of `.+` is a greedy search it  will match till the last `)`. Perhaps the `[^\r\n]+` could be replaced with `.+`, if you dare.  But that could match to much I guess.

Comment: thanks for the advise. I was able to get a very specific solution for this case, fingers crossed I don't find any more weird ones :)
`(\blogDebug)(\b\(.*\).*)\n*\s*(\b.*)\)`

Comment: So some are not on a single line after all. For the multiline with brackets in them? Then this kind of regex would match them : `\blog(\w+)\(((?:[^()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*)\)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sublime but the regex to isolate your function could be:

```
(\blogFun)(\b\(.*)\)
```

And replace :

```
$12$2, type = "bug")
```

Comment: Hey, this works great thank you! For some reason in sublime it got rid of the `logFun` part, but `logFun2$12$2, type = "bug")` seems to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using sublime I used for your cases:

*Find:* `(logFun)(\(.+)\)`

*Replace:* `\12\2, type = "bug")`

If you have also `logBug, logInfo, logWarning` (or even `logDebug(paste("annoying", "case"), msg2 = "data_prep")`) then you could modify just the find part:

*Find:* `(log[A-Z][a-z]*)(\(.+)\)`