# Substitute captured non-ascii letter with upper case

Tags: r, regex, pcre

Is it possible to replicate, using only regex and only base R (only using the g*sub() functions), the following...

```
sub("(i)", "\\U\\1", "string", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "strIng"
```

For non-ascii letters?

```
# Hoped for output
sub("(í)", "?", "stríng", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "strÍng"
```

PS. [R regex flavours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035535/which-regular-expression-engine-type-does-r-use-as-a-standard) are TRE and PCRE.

PS2. I'm using R 4.2.1 with `Sys.getlocale()` giving:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Icelandic_Iceland.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Icelandic_Iceland.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Icelandic_Iceland.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Icelandic_Iceland.utf8"
```

Comment: I get the expected result in my locale `sub("(í)", "\\U\\1", "stríng", perl = TRUE)` returns
`[1] "strÍng"`

Comment: When I say base R I mean no additional packages loaded.

Comment: `sub("(í)", "\\U\\1", "stríng", perl = TRUE)` works well with `"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, so perphaps I've come across a bug?

Comment: I can't repro even after I use `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Icelandic")`.

Comment: What about `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Icelandic.utf8")`?

Comment: In "R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)", with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Icelandic.utf8")`, I get `[1] "stríng"` after running `sub("(í)", "\\U\\1", "stríng", perl = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```r
x="stríng"
gr <- gregexpr("í", x)
mat <- regmatches(x, gr)
regmatches(x, gr) <- lapply(mat, toupper)
# > x
# > [1] "strÍng"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/5qkxBH).

Comment: Nice but I was looking to work directly with regex match/replace.

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly more involved/explicit solution that only uses base R:

```
sub_nascii <- function(pattern, string) {
  matches <- gregexpr(pattern, string)[[1]]
  
  for (i in matches) {
    substr(string, i, i) <- toupper(substr(string, i, i))
  }
  string
}

sub_nascii(pattern = "í", "stríng")
```

This works in my locale where `sub` on it's own doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what happens there, but also works on mine while `sub` does not

Comment: I've just edited it to allow you to pass any regex to the `pattern` argument, if that helps?

Comment: Impressive but I was looking to work directly with regex match/replace.