# Replace characters only if it is not repeating

Tags: r, gsub

Is there a way to replace a character only if it is not repeating, or repeating a certain number of times?

```r
str = c("ddaabb", "daabb", "aaddbb", "aadbb")
gsub("d{1}", "c", str)
[1] "ccaabb" "caabb"  "aaccbb" "aacbb" 

#Expected output
[1] "ddaabb" "caabb"  "aaddbb" "aacbb"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds in your regex to exclude cases where `d` is preceeded or followed by another `d`:

```r
gsub("(?<!d)d(?!d)", "c", str, perl=TRUE)
```

Edit: adding `perl=TRUE` as suggested by OP. For more info about regex engine in R see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035535/which-regular-expression-engine-type-does-r-use-as-a-standard)

Comment: This throws an error on my console. Adding perl = TRUE fixed it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm not familiar with R so didn't know exactly what regex engine it uses... Added your comment to my answer!

Comment: If you're really into pain,  consider  `foo <- unlist(strsplit(str, '');   bar <- rle(foo)` and then look for instances of `bar$lengths ==1`     :-)

Comment: This regex works, but only specifically for  single-instances of "d" .  If  @Maël  wants to find **any** single char,  then you'll need a rather more tricky regex whereas my hack in my previous comment will work.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've added "or repeating a specified number of times,"  the regex-based approaches may get messy.  Thus I submit my wacky code from a previous comment.

```
foo <- unlist(strsplit(str, '')
bar <- rle(foo)
```

and then look for instances of `bar$lengths == desired_length`  and use the returned indices to locate (by summing all `bar$lengths[1:k]` )  the position in the original sequence.  If you only want to replace a specific character, check the corresponding value of `bar$values[k]` and selectively replace as desired.