# Regex that extracts values between specific characters at beginning and end of string

Tags: regex, stringr, gsub

I have a comment field in a dataset that I need to extract some numbers from. The string looks like this. The data I want would to extract that series120_count =1 and crossing success =2

```
x <- "series120_count[1]; crossing_success[2]; tag_comments[small]"
```

I've tried a few things but can't quite get it. For example, my attempt to isolate series120_count is below, but it's not quite there yet.

```
str_extract(x, "(?<=series120_count)(.+)(?=\\; )")
```

Ideally, I would like something that matches "series120_count[" at the start, and ends when the bracket closes "]". I'd like to be able to change this as well to get the crossing success by just subbing out the first match with "crossing_success["

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the lookbehind assertion for both strings and extract the digits, you can use:

```
\b(?<=crossing_success\[|series120_count\[)\d+(?=])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?<=crossing_success\[|series120_count\[)` Positive lookbehind, assert one of the alternatives to the left
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P079wB/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##XY5BCoMwFET3OUVwldAWqtsqHiQJIabBCibK/1@w0LunaXHldngzbyDneRrAwVsgwZRGkIztvL3xCgNMAevmbv2yJVK1eXAPC2KhLG7eB0TVlJDcWJAYQyJUGN08m4qtjihA@i9pPYi@7c5lrdXnJCmR1Pp5EX1nZMWiI/8K@Bsp72zYCZwnWwxiv/JDIdlajpM4YMly/gI)

```
library(stringr)

x <- "series120_count[1]; crossing_success[2]; tag_comments[small]"
pattern <- "\\b(?<=crossing_success\\[|series120_count\\[)\\d+(?=])"
matches <- str_extract_all(x, pattern)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2"
```

---

Alternatively you can use a capture group

```
\b(?:crossing_success|series120_count)\[(\d+)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZlYlVc/1)

Comment: I was curious if `perl=TRUE` is needed as your lookbehind employs an alternation. It appears that R's standard regex engine is the [tcl regex library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035535/which-regular-expression-engine-type-does-r-use-as-a-standard), and that library [does not support lookbehinds](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), with or without alternations. Does `library(stringr)` invoke an engine based on Perl's?

Comment: Thanks Tfb, this worked well and your explanation was extremely helpful.